# SQL date conversion HHMMSS.CCCNNNNNN to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have data in this format : 114643.052303537 (HHMMSS.CCCNNNNNN).

I need to convert it to this format : 2018-04-25 12:40:59.573 (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm), strip of the date part ( i.e. 2018-04-25 ) and calculate the time difference between two formats.

Could you please help with this?

Comment: Provide what you have tried so far, and why do you have "C" in the tags?

Comment: It isn't remotely clear how the `114643` part becomes `12:40:59`.  It also isn't clear what you mean by 'calculate the time difference between two formats'.  The 'difference between two values' makes sense.  But the conversion of a value from one format to another shouldn't change the time except to the extent precision is lost.

Comment: 2018-04-25 12:40:59.573 is 084059.348708957 ( difference is 4 hours) .

Comment: I think you've obfuscated the question with your wording.  You shouldn't have talked about converting, if I understand correctly, you just want the time difference between two different formats.   What format do you want the difference in?   What is the desired result based on the sample data?

Comment: 2018-04-25 12:40:59.573 without the date (2018-04-25) is 4 hours more than 084059.348708957.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I need the time difference in hh:mi:ss.mmm format

Comment: Now you're confusing me even more.  Where did 084059 come from?

Comment: I think 084059  was just another example `time` in the `varchar` format @TabAlleman. Definitely can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the time difference in hh:mi:ss.mmm format

The way to get this is to convert BOTH values to milliseconds (looking at only the time portion for the value that has a date); calculate the difference with simple subtraction, and then convert the result to hh:mi:ss.mmm with division and modulo operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @dt datetime = '2018-04-25 12:40:59.573'
declare @dunno varchar(16) = '114643.052303537'
```

Strip the date off the datetime and give it today's date

```
getdate() + right(convert(varchar,@dt,113),12)
```

Convert the varchar to time and give it today's date

```
getdate() + left(stuff(stuff(@dunno,3,0,':'),6,0,':'),8)
```

Find the milliseconds between them

```
datediff(millisecond,getdate() + left(stuff(stuff(@dunno,3,0,':'),6,0,':'),8),getdate() + right(convert(varchar,@dt,113),12))
```

Put it all together in your format

```
select
    convert(char(13),
            dateadd(millisecond,
                    datediff(millisecond,getdate() + left(stuff(stuff(@dunno,3,0,':'),6,0,':'),8),getdate() + right(convert(varchar,@dt,113),12)),
                    '01/01/00'),
            14)
```

Depending on the speed of your server and other code, it'd be wise to use a variable for `GETDATE()` at the beginning to prevent millisecond, or even second differences during conversion.

```
declare @dt datetime = '2018-04-25 12:40:59.573'
declare @dunno varchar(16) = '114643.052303537'
declare @today datetime = getdate()

declare @dunno2 datetime
declare @dt2 datetime

set @dt2 = @today + right(convert(varchar,@dt,113),12)
set @dunno2 = @today + left(stuff(stuff(@dunno,3,0,':'),6,0,':'),8)

select
    convert(char(13),
        dateadd(millisecond,
                datediff(millisecond,@dunno2,@dt2),
                '01/01/00'),
        14)
```